# (Python) How to do matching between two csv files and return the common elements

Tags: python, csv, matching, multi-index

These are the tables that I am trying to match:
[table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dol0s.png) and
[table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYBaf.png)

```
table1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Patrick', 'Amy', 'Krish', 'Jack']})
table2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Patrick', 'Patrick', 'Jack', 'Amy', 'Rachel', 'Kim', 'Amy'],
                       'Age': [20,19,19,18, 45, 32, 17],
                       'Number of Job Offer': [1,2,3,4, 5, 6, 8] })
```

This is the expected outcome:
[expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epsQm.png)

Can anyone please show me how I can get that in Python? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas and load up your tables into dataframes then merge them. See [here](https://kanoki.org/2019/07/04/pandas-difference-between-two-dataframes/) for more information about comparing rows

Should be something along the lines of

```py
common = table1.merge(table2, how = 'inner' ,indicator=False)
```

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks Ryan

Comment: @WuKris, If you feel the answer helped you, you could [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).